# The replier's From email address is modified when Marketing Cloud RMM forwards an email to the routing address

Tags: marketing-cloud

We've set up RMM to forward replies to routing address and SFMC adds our subdomain to the replier's From email address (i.e. replier@gmail.com becomes replier.gmail.com@oursubdomain.com). However, their reply-to address remains the same.

It seems like DMARC Forward Reply Rewrite is enabled, but we were advised not to touch it as that may affect email deliverability.

Is there any workaround to this? And what will happen if we disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So domains such as yahoo.com restrict sending from domains that are not yahoo.com. So you can not send email from SFMC using a yahoo.com email address. This directly impacts RMM message forwarding. Any ISP the respect DMARC forwarding would reject this message and you would never receive the reply

Many large ISP use this restrictive DMARC policy and thus replies you not be sent.

RMM ensures replies are delivered by rewriting the domain they are sent from.

Answer (score 0):

I hit same problem. You can find an article covering how it behaves here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_dmarc_fwd_reply_rewrite.htm&type=5

The only workaround is to use "direct forwards" which disables RMM feature in specific sender profile. This will use same from address and reply to address which could led you to use "on behalf" emails and affects deliverability.